# Import/execute a module and call function from parent module

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm trying to call an external python script from my django app. I want to call a function from the parent module in the external python script. I tried the following ways.

1. Using subprocess.call : In this case, i'm not able to use the functions from the parent file. The target function uses Django models to do some db operations.
2. Import external file : I tried importing the external file using **import**(), but i cannot access the functions defined in the parent module.

Sample code :

```
from app.models import x

def save():
    print x.objects.all()    

def do_stuff():
    subprocess.call('external_script')


#----------External script --------
''' some code here '''

#Calling save function from parent 
save()
```

How do i achieve this?

Comment: What does it mean "calling function from parent module" to you? Is there some module imported inside that script? Or it is an submodule and you're trying to access module that contains that submodule?

Comment: Are you saying that you have a save method in app.models and you are trying to call that?

Comment: @GwynBleidD In the given code, i'm calling external script from first program and that external script needs to access a function defined in the first program - save( ) function in this case

Comment: @idjaw No, the save method is using one of the django models inside

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to edit that external module and you're calling some function from it, not just importing that, you can pass an callback from first module:

```
def save():
    pass # do something here

def execute_external_module():

    from external_module import some_function
    some_function(save)
```

```
def some_function(callback=None):
    # do something here

    if callback is not None:
        callback()
```

Answer (score 3):

A module knows nothing of where it is imported, specifically, a module's global is freshly created when it is imported. Thus if the importer is not cooperative, an imported module can never touch an object that lives in importer's namespace. If a module needs to call a function in parent's namespace, its parent must pass that function to the module. Concretely:

```
#child
def do_stuff(parents_function):
    pass
```

```
#parent
def func():
    pass

import child
child.do_stuff(func)
```

However, modules are not perfectly isolated, due to the cache. Therefore, if you know the name of parent module, you can do this:

```
#child
import parent
def do_stuff():
    parent.func()
```

```
#parent
import child
def func():
    pass
child.do_stuff()
```